# Select2 JQuery no me carga resultados AJAX

Tags: jquery, select2

es la primera vez que acudo a buscar ayuda en stack overflow y espero que me puedan ayudar, ya que, saben mucho más que yo. Resulta que manejo un plugin de Wordpress llamado "Wishlist Member" que me permite crear membresías para dar acceso a contenidos. Actualmente estoy haciendo una interfaz de administración (no es ningún plugin wordpress o theme) y necesito mostrar todas mis membresías en un select. Para eso estoy empleando el plugin de JQuery Select2 que me ha funcionado bien en otras ocasiones pero, en esta oportunidad, no logro saber qué sucede:

Este es archivo php en el que consulto las membresías y las traigo en formato JSON:

```
include('../API.php');  

$response = $api->get('/levels'); 
$response = unserialize($response);


$response=$response['levels']['level'];


$json_membership = [];      

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($response); $i++){


$json_membership[] = ['id'=>$response[$i]['id'], 'text'=>$response[$i]['name']];

   }

    echo json_encode($json_membership);
```

He verificado este archivo en el navegador y devuelve la información en el formato JSON correctamente. Pero ya en el Select2 me dice que no se pudieron cargar los resultados:

```
$('.memberships').select2({

placeholder: "",
allowClear: true,
width: 'resolve',
language: "es",
    ajax: {
       url: "cursos/ajax_membership.php",
       type: "post",
       dataType: 'json',
       delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
return {
  searchTerm: params.term 
};
 },
 processResults: function (response) {
   return {
     results: response
    };
   },
      cache: false
     }
    });
```

Este es mi Select:

```
<label for="membership"> 
Asociar Membresía
<select class="memberships form-control" id="membership" style="width:100%" name="membership" required>
</select>
</label>
```

He intentando muchas cosas y no logro resolverlo. Agradecería inmensamente su colaboración.

Comment: Yo para estas cosas utilizo funcionalidad "fetch" nativo de JavaScript. Rapido y devuelve Promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya pude resolver mi inconveniente! resulta que el archivo ajax_membership.php de respuesta me estaba devolviendo un código HTML al inicio antes de la información en formato JSON entonces no podía ser leída como tal. Todo esto se debía a que en el archivo API.php que está incluido en ajax_membership.php contenía etiquetas html innecesarias y lo único que tuve que hacer fue borrarlas y no dejar espacios ni antes ni después de las etiquetas PHP. Ahora sí funciona! Gracias a quien me recomendó usar FETCH. Lo estuve haciendo también y gracias a ello fue que pude encontrar mi error. Mejores Saludos!